# Storing and retrieving a serialized array in a Symfony2 form

Tags: php, forms, serialization, symfony, doctrine-orm

In my database there is a table, which has a column of the type text. This column holds a serialized array. This array is read and stored by another application, and I cannot change its format.

The serialized array holds a selection of database names, table names and column names in two different languages.

I would like to write a controller, entity, form, etc. in Symfony2 that is able to modify this serialized array.

There is a script that I can use that can provide an array of all possible db names, table names and column names that each serialized array may contain.

The goal is to present a list of check boxes where users can select db's, tables and columns. Next, they can do a translation of the names.

Since all data is so volatile, I am not sure whether this is even possible in Symfony2.

An alternative is to make the following entities: { database, table, column } and do it fully OO. And then I could export a selection in a serialized array, to the external application that expects it that way...

Can you guys follow my reasoning? Am I overlooking a strategy here...?

Added:
The array is a nested array up to the fifth degree. Databases contain tables, which contain columns. And every item has an original name and a translated name.

Comment: Can you give a good example of the array that you have and how you want to manage this array?

Comment: I have added some more detail on the structure of the array. The management of the array... well that is pretty much my question :) How can I manage it in Symfony2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you answered your own guestion:

```
An alternative is to make the following entities: { database, table, column } and do it fully OO.
And then I could export a selection in a serialized array, to the external application that 
expects it that way...
```

You would start with a master entity mapped to your table.

```
class SomeEntity
{
    protected $serializedInfo;

    public getDatabases()
    {
        // Process serializedInfo into an array of database objects and return
```

You then pass SomeEntity to SomeEntityFormType which in turn uses a collection of DatabaseFormTypes.  The DatabaseFormType then has a collection of TableFormTypes and so on.

Eventually your form would be posted and SomeEntity would be updated.  You then serialize before posting.  Should be straight forward.  Might be a bit more challenging if you want users to add information but even then it is doable.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's really late but I was really busy with university so I couldn't answer sooner

This is what I think is the best to do

Imagine that the table that contains the column which contains your array is called foo

So you make an entity which is called Foo and contains a field(type text) that has the name you like

Now the tricky part is to make an object called Database that contains all the relations you need(To a Table object and Table objects to column Objects)

So even though I told you to make the field type as text you will pas the object Database to this field

So how it's going to work

The Database object will have a __string method that will return the serialized array of the object the way you want

This way when doctrine2 tries to save the Database object in the text field it will be saved as the string that __string method returns

And you will have getDatabase that will converts the serialized array to the database object

This is the idea that I have and not sure if it suits you or not

Comment: This is an interesting solution. Although I've chosen another approach for the moment, I will try this once on a smaller scale to see how this could work. Thanks, PHP lover!